# Ignore XML Namespace (TAL) in SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext2, plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

I'm using SublimeText 2 and SublimeLinter, and I develop for Zope and Plone.  In the page templates (.pt) I get lots of errors for namespace problems, which I would like to either fix or have SublimeLinter ignore.

For example:

```
<p tal:replace="structure some_content">Content</p>
```

...throws the following SublimeLinter error:

```
Namespace error: Namespace prefix tal for replace on p is not defined
```

I would like to ignore (or fix!) these, since there's a lot of TAL in page templates, and showing errors for each statement isn't helpful.

So the question essentially is, how do I tell SublimeLinter to ignore Namespace Errors, or am I missing something from my page template to include the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you a) use the XML syntax highlighter (View -> Syntax -> XML), and b) declare the `tal`, `metal` and `i18n` namespaces properly, then `xmllint` (the command line tool used by SublimeLinter for this task) will be perfectly happy with TAL templates.

For example, using an HTML body tag:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="someprojectid">
```

and I can use `tal`, `metal` and `i18n` attributes and tags at will.

Comment: I was already using XML syntax highlighter. I'd copied the .pt stub from another file and it didn't include the proper xmlns's. Adding them solved it. I guess I was wondering if they were necessary. In this case, yes! Thanks Martijn.